# How can I stop webpages directing me to the mobile site (Firefox)?

Tags: firefox, arm, web

I've recently started using Arch Linux on a Chromebook C201 (arm). However, when using Firefox, many websites seem to direct me to their mobile site, which is getting quite irritating. Perhaps they are assuming I am using a mobile device, as it has an arm cpu?

What is it that is flagging the Chromebook as a mobile device and is there some global setting in Firefox I can use to flag that it is a desktop installation?

Comment: Have you tried changing your user agent string to match that of a non-ARM firefox?

Comment: @Fox where would I do that, and what string would I use?

Comment: Mine is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0`. There's an about:config setting (`general.useragent.override`, which probably does not yet exist) or various add-ons to that effect

Comment: @Fox I don't see that config setting, but I will try some of the add-ons and see if they help. Thanks

Comment: The config setting is respected but not created by default. You can create it, but the add-ons are arguably easier to use